# Can't resolve 'react-firebase-hooks'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, next.js, npm-install

I am working on Next js project and I installed packeage named react-firebase-hooks.
My Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "whatsapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "firebase": "^8.3.1",
    "next": "10.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

But when I tried to import it in Next js file _app.js like

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

But I am getting error:

```
error - ./pages/_app.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-firebase-hooks'
  1 | import '../styles/globals.css'
> 2 | import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks"
  3 |
  4 | function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
```

I can't understand why this error is coming coz I have Installed the package but still getting error like this

```
PS E:\Next\whatsapp> node -v
v14.16.0
PS E:\Next\whatsapp> npm -v
7.6.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Friend just import it like this "import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';"

Answer (score 1):

Its maybe just something that went wrong with the installation try remove `node_modules` and `install` it again.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install --save react-firebase-hooks
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue too, I had to restart my server and it worked normally after the restart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).